# Import css File in asp.net core2 with react redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, asp.net-core-2.0

My Header.tsx is:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import "./header.css"

export default class Header extends React.Component {
    public render() {
        return <div id="Header">

        </div>;
    }
}
```

and header.css is:

```
#Header{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}
```

When I run m project i get this error:

```
NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Module parse failed: E:\Tools\ClientApp\components\header.css Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader) for import and use css files in react applications.

First install css-loader:

```
npm install --save-dev css-loader
```

Then add css-loader to your [webpack](https://webpack.js.org) config:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I change the background-color in #Header but not work, why ?

Comment: There is no correlation with compile css, your problem maybe with css priority. Try "background: red !important;"

Comment: I'm new to react and a bit confused whether I need to install css-loader, so leave an update. As of `react-scripts` 1.1.5, css-loader can be used via [react-scripts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts), which is now included in dependencies by default in dotnet-new react and reactredux template. As [React doc says here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-stylesheet), another way is use `src/index.css`.